# NullPointer Exception when opening pdf (MUPDF Android)

Tags: java, android, pdf, nullpointerexception, rendering

I have a library project, which is the MUPDF rendering library. I am using my project called OPENER, to ask the library project to display a pdf. Like this:

```
String s= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/Download/Adobe Reader/Getting Started with Adobe Reader.pdf";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MuPDFActivity.class);

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setData(uri);





startActivity(intent);
```

I think the pdf does open up(i cannot see it ever) because the Logcat says this:

> 07-16 12:21:02.678: D/dalvikvm(2317): No JNI_OnLoad found in
>   /data/data/com.example.opener/lib/libmupdf.so 0xa6ac31c8, skipping
>   init 07-16 12:21:02.690: E/libmupdf(2317): ***Opening document***... 07-16
>   12:21:02.706: I/alert(2317): alert_init 07-16 12:21:02.706:
>   E/libmupdf(2317): ***Done!*** 07-16 12:21:02.738: D/dalvikvm(2317):
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 181K, 3% free 8176K/8391K, paused 13ms+0ms, total
>   22ms

But After the above message, i get a nullpointerException. Here is the full error message:

```
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.opener/com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.CallbackApplication$MuPDFCallbackClass.sendGaiView(CallbackApplication.java:16)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.updatePageNumView(MuPDFActivity.java:966)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.access$5(MuPDFActivity.java:949)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity$4.onMoveToChild(MuPDFActivity.java:430)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.ReaderView.setDisplayedViewIndex(ReaderView.java:94)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.createUI(MuPDFActivity.java:654)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:396)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-16 12:21:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(2317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

What is the problem, where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Have you debugged the code at all?

Comment: I downloaded the code from github.https://github.com/joniks/Android-MuPDF

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: no, i have not, i need help with where to start debugging

Comment: I have informed the author about said issue

Comment: I dont see why I am getting downvotes, It is a valid question about how to get a library running in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/Download/AdobeReader/Getting Started with Adobe Reader.pdf";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MuPDFActivity.class);

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setData(uri);



//if document protected with password
intent.putExtra("password", "PDF document password");

//if you need highlight link boxes
intent.putExtra("linkhighlight", true);

//if you don't need device sleep on reading document
intent.putExtra("idleenabled", false);

//document name
intent.putExtra("docname", "PDF document file name");




startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: please try with latest commit

Comment: IT WORKS! , I want to upvote and accept your answer, but there really is no 'answer ' right now. could you post the changes you made from the commit?

Comment: But its not working if you choose path from sdcard. Can you provide solution for it ?